# Call custom function of custom membership provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a custom membership provider which looks like this:

```
public class PMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public IMembershipService Account { get; set; }

    public PMembershipProvider()
    {
        this.Account = new UserModel();

    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return Account.Login(username, password);
    }

    public void DisposeContext()
    {
        Account.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And membership service interface which looks like this:

```
public interface IMembershipService
{
    bool Login(string userName, string password);
    void Dispose();
}
```

Thus when I go to log in the user I can call the login method of my User Model like so:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login(UserModel model)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.name, model.password)) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.name, false, MvcApplication.BASE_URL);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

I'm running into some strange user issues which I believe are associated with an undisposed EF object context. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237398/1324019) I'd like to try manually disposing the object context used by the membership provider. I want this to happen at the end of the request, and for that I want to override the `Dispose` method on my User Controller:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    Membership.DisposeContext(); //this is what I want to do, but it doesn't work
}
```

When I try to call the `DisposeContext` method of my custom membership provider it can't find the method. ('System.Web.Security.Membership' does not contain a definition for 'DisposeContext')

How can I call my `DisposeContext` method **on the same object** used by Membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Membership` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) only provides static methods to call the known methods on the default membership provider. To call a custom method, you'll need to access the [`Membership.Provider` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.provider.aspx), cast it to your custom provider, and then call the method:

```
((PMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DisposeContext();
```

Comment: Argh...I tried almost that exact thing. That works though - thanks!