# Recursive Call over an Entity Framework Objects raise SqlTransaction Error

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I'm working with MVC 3 and Entity Framework with c# language. I have a Repository Class which implement an IRepository Interface. In my project, I need a recursive logic for delete objects. It has been implemented by a recursive function. but it raise this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. New transaction is not allowed
>   because there are other threads running in the session.

My code is similar to this:

```
public void Delete(long ObjectId)
{
  if(SomeThing ==true)
  {
    var items = TRepository.Find(o=>o.Id==ObjectId);
    foreach(var t in items)
      {
        Delete(t.ObjectId);
      }
  }
  Delete(ObjectId);
  TRepository.SaveChanges();//here raise error!!!
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlException from Entity Framework - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther)

Comment: Thanks dear Mrnka, what I must do?

Comment: Read the linked question in the first place - it contains answer to your problem. You are most probably trying to call `SaveChanges` inside iteration of query result set due to incorrectly used recursion. Don't call `SaveChanges` in your `Delete` method.

Comment: I fixed my previous error. now I have concurrency problem with entity framework...