# Linq modified get a error message New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, linq

I want modified SQL data using linq, but when I modified, I got into trouble.

I get this error:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

and this is my linq in C#

```
for (int i = 1; i < st.Count(); i++)
{
    string Lesson = i.ToString();

    var query = db.YearCourse_105008
                  .Where(o => o.Day == Day && o.Lesson == Lesson)
                  .Select(o => new
                    {
                        O_GUID = o.OpenCourseGUID,
                        Lesson = o.Lesson
                    });

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var PK = db.YearCourse_105008.Find(item.O_GUID);
        PK.Day = Day;
        PK.RC_MAJORCODE = st[i];
        PK.Lesson = i.ToString();

        db.Entry(PK).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `query` is `IQueryable` that can return objects, certainly you need to realise it using `IEnumerable` collection (e.g. `List`) when iterating query results using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in query.ToList()) // --> here the source should be IEnumerable collection
{
    var PK = db.YearCourse_105008.Find(item.O_GUID);
    PK.Day = Day;
    PK.RC_MAJORCODE = st[i];
    PK.Lesson = i.ToString();

    db.Entry(PK).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

or convert query results from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` first:

```
var query = db.YearCourse_105008
                  .Where(o => o.Day == Day && o.Lesson == Lesson)
                  .Select(o => new
                    {
                        O_GUID = o.OpenCourseGUID,
                        Lesson = o.Lesson
                    }).ToList();
```

NB: In addition, `db.SaveChanges()` method may placed outside `foreach` loop to update all modified entries at once, hence you don't need to save every modified entries per each iteration.

Related problems:

[New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session LINQ To Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096509/new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-there-are-other-threads-running-in-the-se)

[SqlException from Entity Framework - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther)

[Entity Framework - "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085732/entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-there-are-other-threa)

Comment: Thank you ! your answer help to me

Comment: I'll add that `db.SaveChanges();` should be called outside of the `foreach`.