# Message = "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to copy data row by row from `ProductStatisticsTemp`table to `ProductStatistics` table.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Copy_DatatoProductStatistics()
    {
        string errormsg = "";
        //var incomplete_product_result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductStatistics>("Copy_ProductStatistics");
        var str = from a in db.ProductStatisticsTemp select a;

        ProductStatistics ls = new ProductStatistics();

        try
        {
            foreach (var val in str) // iterator the data from the list and insert them into the listSecond
            {
                var product = db.Product.Find(val.Product_ID);

                try
                {

                    if (product.ProductID == val.Product_ID & product.ProductTitleEn == val.ProductNameEn & product.ProductTitleAr == val.ProductNameAr)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.SalesVolumes) | !String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Target) | !String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Profitability) | !String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.AnnualGrowthRate))
                            {
                                ls.Product_ID = val.Product_ID;
                                ls.ProductNameEn = val.ProductNameEn;
                                ls.ProductNameAr = val.ProductNameAr;
                                ls.Profitability = val.Profitability;
                                ls.Target = val.Target;
                                ls.SalesVolumes = val.SalesVolumes;
                                ls.Subsidary_ID = val.Subsidary_ID;
                                ls.AnnualGrowthRate = val.AnnualGrowthRate;

                                db.ProductStatistics.Add(ls);

                            }

                               db.SaveChanges();

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            errormsg = ex.Message;
                        }


                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errormsg = "Product ID or Product Name Doesnt match with existing details";
                }

            }           


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errormsg = ex.Message;                
        }


        return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "FileUpload", new { error = errormsg });

    }
```

but after `db.SaveChanges();` above line its directing to `catch (Exception ex)` . once I debug I can see following inner exception message

> Message = "New transaction is not allowed because there are other
>   threads running in the session."

Comment: Never ever call you database code from controller code ...Create a Data Access Layer which you should be calling from controller

Comment: If your google that error message and read the first few hits you will understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
IList<ProductStatistics> str = from a db.ProductStatisticsTemp select a;
foreach (var val in str)
{

    // your code
}
```

You need to call EF and try to return it into an `IList<T>` of that target type and then we can use a loop on the `IList<T>`

You can also check this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther)

Comment: Don't we need in general case use `.ToList()` in the end of EF query?

Comment: @teovankot:- Yes we need to.

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<project_name.Models.ProductStatisticsTemp>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<project_name.Models.ProductStatisticsTemp>'.` getting this error