# Problem in Saving Data after Upgrading from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

After upgrading .NET core version from 2.2 to 3.0 I got error on this:

```
_repository.Insert(new RequestStatusHistory()
{
 RequestId = requestModel.Id ,
 RequestStatusId = newRequestStatusId 
});


public void Insert(T entity)
{         
 this._entity.Add(entity);
 _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the error is:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

What should I do?
`

Comment: Check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther)

Comment: I don't have any loop!

Comment: Add more details about the repositories `Insert` method to the question.

Comment: You are calling single database context in multiple methods. if you use foreach loop to insert, don't call savechanges inside foreach loop

Comment: The bug was there from the start, you just didn't notice it. You're using a DbContext from multiple threads *and* using the Generic Repository **anti**pattern. How many insertions is that `SaveChanges` going to make? 1? 2? 10? You have no way of knowing. `SaveChanges` persists **all** changes since the last time it was called. It can easily perform some updates and deletions too. Contexts are meant to be short-lived too, just like connections

Comment: The solution is to *not* use the generic repository and *not* use a global context. A DbContext is essentially a UoW, by creating a global one you're breaking that functionality. Check [No Need for Repositories and Unit of Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for a detailed explanation

Comment: If you *remove* `Insert` altogether, add any entities you want normally with `DbSet.Add` and only call `SaveChanges` just once, just before you dispose the context, you'll probably get rid of the problem and improve performance a lot. The error complains there are multiple active transactions. Perhaps you explicitly tried to start one, even though `SaveChanges` is atomic? Or you are still reading from a query? Without the call that called `Insert` it's impossible to say